# How to programmatically add corner radius to search bar using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a search bar in my navigation controller written in Objective-C and I want to add a corner radius to it similar to how it is done in Swift:

`searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 10`

How do I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[searchBar layer] setCornerRadius: 10];
```

Comment: or `searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a semicolon to make it compatible with Objective-C:

```c
searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

To get the equivalent property/method names in each languages, you can search the documentation and switch from one language to the other in a simple click on top of the page:

- `layer` in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer)/[Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer?language=objc)
- `cornerRadius` in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius)/[Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius?language=objc)